# How to turn View into Bitmap including the view behind it?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I have a layout which has an `ImageView` and then a `LinearLayout` which contains `TextViews` on top of that, so what this looks like on the screen is an image with text on top of it.

Layout is like this.

```
<RelativeLayout>
 <ImageView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- textviews -->
    </LinearLayout>
 </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am able to get the Linear layout as a Bitmap using this code, but the bitmap does not contain the background image, it is just black background. I want it to be the layout along with the image that is behind it.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);

Bitmap imageToShare = loadBitmapFromView(linearLayout ); 

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    view.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I seem to have worked around the issue by putting another Relative layout which contains both the ImageView and LinearLayout in it. Then I generate the bitmap from this RelativeLayout instead of the LinearLayout.